# Averaging list of lists python numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, python-3.4

I have to find mean of each list in a list of lists.
I am using numpy.
I tried

```
numpy.mean(a, axis=1)
```

It works fine when all lists are equal in length.

In my case each list may be of different length. It is giving

```
IndexError: `tuple index out of range`
```

Code to reproduce

```
import numpy
data = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,6]])
print(numpy.mean(data, axis=1))
```

Desired output

```
[ 2.  5.]
```

Comment: What's the shape of `data`?  How many axes?

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet could work:

```
data_mean = [numpy.mean(lst, axis=0) for lst in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```py
numpy.mean([numpy.mean(list, axis=1) for list in lists], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop in the lists:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6]])
means = []
for row in data:
    means.append(numpy.mean(row))

print(means)
```